# Importing Array to object - Angular 2+

Tags: arrays, angular, object

I have service that gets me array of types:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.coreService.getByType( this.name ).subscribe(
            response => { this.handleSuccess( response ); },
            error => { console.error( error ); });

}

handleSuccess( coreTypes ) {
    var data = [];
    var pushedItems = [];
    coreTypes.forEach( ( coreType ) => {
        var entriesForType = [];
        entriesForType.push( coreType );    
            if ( entriesForType.length > 0 ) {
                entriesForType.forEach( entry => this.data.push( entry ) );
                this.data = data;
            if (data.length > 0) {
                data.forEach( d =>  this.item.value = d && pushedItems.push(this.item));
            }
                if(this.gridOptions.api !== null){
                    this.gridOptions.api.setRowData( this.pushedItems );
                }
            } 
    });
}
```

Currently, this.data is creating me array like this `this.data = ["one","two","three"]`

What i need is to create array of object that will look like this

```
pushedItems = [{value:"one"},{value:"two"},{value:"three"}];
```

I defined item: Object; and in contstructor `this.item = {value:""};`

But in function, when i set `this.item.value = d` ... it keeps showing me error "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Object' ...Any help to achieve array like pushedItems?

Comment: Use this in subscriber method like this `subscribe( (response:any)=> {   this.handleSuccess( response ); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handleSuccess() {
  const p = [];
  this.coreTypes.forEach(coretype => {
   let obj = {};
   obj[coretype] = coretype;
   p.push(obj);
  });
}

handleSuccess() {
  const p = [];
  this.coreTypes.forEach(coretype => {      
   p.push({coretypes:coretypes});
  });
}
```

Comment: Code only answer can't be good answers. Could you explain a little ?

Comment: Second example is working just fine ...you can just type p.push({value: coretype});

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing your object as:

```
arr.push(this.object);
```

you should just push it like:

```
arr.push({
  value: this.object,
})
```